# Extract key values using redis-cli

Tags: redis

I am trying to extract key values from Redis CLI and migrate the same to Mongo. However I am a newbee in Redis and have no idea.

```
redis 10.38.137.143:6382> KEYS *26428600*
1) "26428600:favorites"
```

How can I print what is contained in the key?

Comment: Have you tried a `GET` or `DUMP`?

Comment: redis 10.38.137.143:6382> GET 26428600:favorites
(error) ERR Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

Comment: `GET` is meant for string types. and `DUMP` is more generic and just dumps bytes. You can use `TYPE` to identify the type that a key holds and then use the appropriate getter. See the [redis docs](http://redis.io/commands) for more information of the available commands.

Comment: redis 127.0.0.1:6382> TYPE 26428600:favorites
set

Not sure how can I read the value now

Comment: smembers would be the command you're looking for in that case